# Determine $\frac{\partial\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}}{\partial b}$ from $f(x,a,b)=0$ with implicit function theorem

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem

Say I have the following:
$$f(x,a,b)=0\qquad\text{(1)}$$
Applying the implicit function theorem I get something like this:
$$\frac{\partial x(a,b)}{\partial a}=\frac{f'_a}{-f'_x}\qquad\text{(2)}$$
Where $f'_a=\frac{\partial f(\cdot)}{\partial a}$ and $f'_x=\frac{\partial f(\cdot)}{\partial x}$. I am now interested in knowing how a variation in $b$ affects the effect of a variation in $a$ on $x$ (i.e., $\frac{\partial\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}}{\partial b}$).

Can I simply take the derivative of expression (2) or should I apply the implicit function theorem twice to expression (1)?

In the case where I could not, why would it be incorrect?

Many thanks!

Comment: How did you arrive at your result?  Note that $f_1 x_a+f_2=0$ implies $x_a=-f_2/f_1$.

Comment: @MarkViola - Sorry there was a mistake in (2), it has been corrected now. Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: You write $f_1(x(a,b),a,b)  x_a(a,b) +f_2(x(a,b),a,b) =0$ as @MarkViola said and now you differentiate this wrt $b$ using the Chain Rule. There are quite a few terms, but you can extract $x_{ab}$ from this.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, the two methods seem equivalent in the case I consider.

**Method 1: applying IFT twice**

We start with
$$f(x(a,b),a,b)=0\qquad \text{(1)}$$
We differentiate (1) with respect to $a$:
$$f_xx_a+f_a=0\qquad \text{(2)}$$
Where $f_x$ and $f_a$ are the partial derivatives of $f(\cdot)$ with respect to $x$ and $a$ respectively. Similarly, $x_a$ is the partial derivative of $x(a,b)$ with respect to $a$. Now we differentiate (2) with respect to $b$:
$$f_xx_{ab}+f_{xx}x_ax_b+f_{xa}x_b+f_{xb}x_a+f_{ab}=0\qquad\text{(3)}$$
Rearranging (3) gives:
$$x_{ab}=\frac{f_{xx}x_ax_b+f_{xa}x_b+f_{xb}x_a+f_{ab}}{-f_x}\qquad\text{(4)}$$

**Method 2: directly differentiating $\pmb{x_a}$**

Let's start with:
$$x_a=\frac{f_a}{-f_x}\qquad\text{(1')}$$
Differentiating (1') this expression with respect to $b$ gives:
$$x_{ab}=\frac{-(f_{ab}+f_{xa}x_b)f_x+f_a(f_{xx}x_b+f_{xb})}{(f_x)^2}=\frac{f_{ab}+f_{xa}x_b}{-f_x}-\frac{f_a}{-f_x}\frac{f_{xx}x_b+f_{xb}}{f_x}\quad\text{(2')}$$
Injecting (1') in (2') and rearranging, we fall back on our feet:
$$x_{ab}=\frac{f_{xx}x_ax_b+f_{xa}x_b+f_{xb}x_a+f_{ab}}{-f_x}$$